# Angular 2 (change) for file upload

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I am using the Angular 2 (change) to detect the uploaded file and trigger the function. But I am facing the problem when I tried to upload the same file again, as there is no change in the file, (change) is not triggered. Please suggest the event binding in this case.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileupload" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
```

Is there any way to reset the input value of type file to empty.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access the file input as a ViewChild and get the files from it.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} '@angular/core';
@Component({
//...
template: `
  <input #fileInput type='file' (change)="fileChanged($event)">
`
//...
})
export class FileInputComponent {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') myFileInput: ElementRef;

  getFileLater() {
    console.log(this.myFileInput.nativeElement.files[0]);
  }

  fileChanged(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

`.files[]` on the nativeElement is always an array even if there is only one file selected (or none, for that matter). It will give you file objects exactly as it would if you accessed `event.target.files` from the `(change)` event so you can do with them what you want after the fact.

It should be mentioned though that when a file is chosen on the file input and the change event is triggered, the file hasn't actually been 'uploaded' anywhere. It just passes the browser a reference to it (with some other meta data) that the client can work with. Actually uploading the files is something you have to program in separately.

**UPDATE:**

In order to force the file input to fire the change event even when choosing a file that was previously selected, the file input has to be reset by clearing its value whenever the Browse button is clicked. Since you're already using jQuery, you can do that like so: `$('#fileupload').val("");`.

[See my forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gdV2bD) for a working example.

Comment: If I browser the same file for the second time as nothing in the element has changes how will (change) detects it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking. The change event **only** fires when the user selects/changes the file input. If you want to get the file that has been selected in the file input separately from when the change events, you have to access the file input element's `files[]` array, as I have shown in my example's `getFileLater()` function.

Comment: I trigger my function using the change event. I browse a file, and then change the data of the file. When I browse the same file again the function wont be triggered by change event because it is the same file.

Comment: Tried your plunker it is working in angular beta, I updated the plunker to angular RC5, It still has the issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/QcZaiB?p=preview

Comment: I think something in RC5 is conflicting with the way the DOM is being queried. If you access the DOM the preferred way for Angular 2 apps (using ViewChild) and reset the value property on the file input's nativeElement, it works fine. See here: https://plnkr.co/edit/gdV2bD

Comment: You can simply do `event.target.value = null` to clear the `FileList` in the `onChange(event)` function.

Comment: `console.log(this.myFileInput)` is undefined in my case. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Is your ElementRef pointing to your input element?
 `@ViewChild('uniqueIdentifier') ...` points to `<input #uniqueIdentifier ...`